# Converting WAV to GSM using pysox

Tags: format, codec, file-conversion, sox, transcoding

I'm experimenting with pysox and trying to simply convert a WAV file to GSM.

I'm currently using the following approach which works just fine:

```
infile = pysox.CSoxStream("input_file.wav")
outfile = pysox.CSoxStream('output_file.gsm','w',infile.get_signal())
chain = pysox.CEffectsChain(infile, outfile)
chain.flow_effects()
outfile.close()
```

I wonder if there's a better/builtin way without using effects (as i'm not applying any effects) .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found that i actually must use libsox effect as i'm changing the rate :

```
 chain.add_effect(pysox.CEffect("rate", ["8k"]))
```

Without adding this line the output appears in slow motion  (since my original file can have different rate)